# How can I use fake sendmail with SwiftMailer on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, smtp, swiftmailer, sendmail.exe

I wish to send emails using PHP on Windows via an external SMTP server.  I must use [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org) for this purpose.

I can send emails via the external SMTP server using PHP's native mail() function and [Fake Sendmail for Windows](http://glob.com.au/sendmail), but I cannot get [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org) working.

### Working Setup Using PHP's mail() Function

Here is the PHP code I use to send mail successfully using the native mail() function.

```
$returnValue = mail
(
   $params['to'     ],
   $params['subject'],
   $params['body'   ],
   "From: Sender McSender <{$params['from']}>"
);

echo "mail() returned "; var_dump($returnValue);
```

Here is the relevant portion of my php.ini file.

```
[mail function]
sendmail_path = "C:\usr\lib\sendmail.exe"
```

[Fake Sendmail for Windows](http://glob.com.au/sendmail) has its own sendmail.ini file, in which I have specified my smtp_server, smtp_port, auth_username, and auth_password.

When I run above PHP code by loading a page in my web browser, the output indicates that the mail() function returns true, and the email arrives at its intended destination as expected.

### Attempted Setup Using [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org) (Not Working)

Attempting to achieve the same result using [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org), I replace my PHP code above with the following, as instructed to in the [SwiftMailer documentation](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#using-the-sendmail-transport).

```
$transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('/usr/lib/sendmail -t');
$mailer    = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message   = Swift_Message::newInstance()
->setSubject($params['subject'])
->setFrom($params['from'])
->setTo($params['to'])
->setBody($params['body']);

$nSent = $mailer->send($message);

echo "Number of emails sent: $nSent\n";
```

When I attempt to run the PHP code above by loading a page in my web browser, the page just loads forever.  I have traced the PHP code in the SwiftMailer library as far as I can, and found that I could not see output from echo statements after the "if ($err = stream_get_contents($pipes[2])) {" line below.  If I cut and paste the 'echo "Okay so far."' and 'die;' lines to after the 'if' condition, either inside or outside the curly braces following the 'if', the page just keeps loading forever.

```
/**
 * Opens a process for input/output.
 */
private function _establishProcessConnection()
{
echo "In StreamBuffer->_establishProcessConnection()\n";
    $command = $this->_params['command'];
    $descriptorSpec = array(
        0 => array('pipe', 'r'),
        1 => array('pipe', 'w'),
        2 => array('pipe', 'w')
        );
    $this->_stream = proc_open($command, $descriptorSpec, $pipes);
    stream_set_blocking($pipes[2], 0);
echo "Okay so far.\n";
die;
    if ($err = stream_get_contents($pipes[2])) {
        throw new Swift_TransportException(
            'Process could not be started [' . $err . ']'
            );
    }
    $this->_in =& $pipes[0];
    $this->_out =& $pipes[1];
}
```

### Things I have Tried Already

- I have tried using -bs instead of -t in the /usr/lib/sendmail command passed to Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance().  I have tried passing no parameter (ie. neither -bs nor -t) also.
- I have tried passing the 'from' parameter the same way as I do in the call to PHP's native mail() function above.  When I did that, SwiftMailer complained that my 'from' address 'does not comply with RFC 2822'.
- I have tried (thanks to Michael Sivolobov's suggestion below), replacing '/usr/lib/sendmail -t' with 'C:\usr\lib\sendmail -t', and with 'C:/usr/lib/sendmail -t'.  In both cases, the page just keeps loading forever.
- I've tried passing no arguments to the Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance() function in the hope that Swift would figure out the path to my sendmail.exe from my php.ini file.  Doing that resulted in the following error "Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified.]"  The exception was thrown from the code section reproduced above.  Passing '-t' and '-bs' had the same effect.

I'm all out of ideas.  Any helpful suggestions anyone can offer on how to get the SwiftMailer code working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After much frustration I decided to ditch SwiftMailer and install PHPMailer instead. I had no problems setting up PHPMailer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use right transport:

```
$transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('C:\usr\lib\sendmail.exe');
```

**UPDATE**
Use this line:

```
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Michael, but it did not help.  I have updated the 'Things I have Tried' section to include your suggestion.

Comment: @Tom, try to use `$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();`

Comment: Thanks again, and good thinking, but that did not solve the problem.  I've updated my question again.

Comment: It's not about no arguments to transport constructor. It's about another Transport Class: `Swift_MailTransport` instead of `Swift_SendmailTransport`

Comment: Oh, right.  Hopefully that will solve the problem for someone else.  I decided to ditch SwiftMailer and install PHPMailer instead.  I had no problems setting up PHPMailer.  Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have installed the [fake sendmail](https://www.glob.com.au/sendmail/) into a local directory like:

```
C:\wamp64\bin\sendmail\sendmail.exe
```

Edit your `php.ini` file like this:

```
sendmail_path = "C:\wamp64\bin\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
```

Edit your `sendmail.ini` file like this:

```
smtp_server=localhost
smtp_port=25
smtp_ssl=none
```

then use [swiftmailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/sending.html) SMTP transport like this:

```
$transport = new Swift_SmtpTransport('localhost', 25);
```

> - `Swift_SendmailTransport` is designed only for (Linux/UNIX) executable.

---

### For Laravel Users

the process is the same but you also need to edit your `.env` file like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=myemail@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="My Name"
```

Comment: Finally.. Thank you! You saved my day!